# Google iOS API thumbnailURL: is not working

Tags: ios, google-api, google-plus

I'm using Google API for my iOS app, and I have this code

```
    [shareBuilder setURLToShare:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://facebook.com/Uncollectible"]];
```

that works well and embeds the url to my post on Google+ as expected.

But another method with deep-link set doesn't:

```
    [shareBuilder setTitle:@"Uncollectible"
           description:@"Stay cool. Stay debtless."
          thumbnailURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://facebook.com/Uncollectible"]];
```

Please advise. Thanks!

Comment: For a start, define "doesn't work"

Comment: url wasn't embedded in the post, and thumbnail not showing

Comment: @SteveCorleone, I am also facing same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: @SteveCorleone, have yo u find any solution for this?